# How to read data in file that contain diffrent size in c++

Tags: c++

[image: pic]

```
 file_name = file_name_out_of_class;
ifstream file(file_name);
if (file.is_open()) {
    string line;
    int temp_sap;
    int temp_sem;
    int temp_cours;
    int temp_cred;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        cout << sizeof(info) << endl;
        //????????
        
    }
}
```

**C++**
This pic contains data of the student I want to store in variables or array, but the problem is who to store it. Because 1st line contain large data and 2nd line contain small data.

Comment: Why the `java` and `C` tags if you are asking about `C++`?

Comment: Any reason why you inserted an image which shows a _Text_ editor? Why didn't you paste the text directly?

Comment: Your data format looks like some kind of key-value pairs. Hence, this could be `std::string key; int value; file >> key >> value;` Then you may compare the `key` with known keys to assign the `value` to the corresponding member. An `if`/`else` cascade would do the job. (For many keys, an array or `std::map` might be considered as well.)

Comment: Side note: `sizeof` gets the size of an object. If the object contains pointers, you'll get the size of yhe pointers, not the size of whatever the pointers point at. `sizeof(info)` will get you the size of an `istringstream` and that size will never change no matter how much data is in the stream. You could have nothing or you could have the Complete Works of Stephen King and the number you get will always be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the most important information, I mean, the column header, or field names, or student attribute is missing, I can only give a general answer.

You should abstract the data in one line into a corresponding data structure. I give you an artificial example. A line, as you did show above, could be structured like this:

First an `ID`, then an `item`, and then, 0, 1 or more pairs of `Evaluators` consisting of `Descriptors` and `Numbers`. All names are arbitrary chosen. If you give the descripition of the content of one line, then I could use that instead. Anyway.

Then we make an abstraction and create a datatype, a struct/class that can hold the data above.

So, first we have something like:

```
struct Evaluator {
    std::string descriptor{};
    unsigned int number{};
};
```

Next we make a abstraction of complete line data, maybe like that

```
struct Record {
    unsigned int ID{};
    unsigned int item{};
    std::vector<Evaluator> eval{};
};
```

the `std::vector` makes the data dynamic. There can be 0,1 or more Evaluators in there.

And then we will use the C++ method of data inpit and output. The `iostream` facilities. You know the inserter `<<` operator and the extractor `>>` operator.

This we will define for our structs.

Then the whole program will look like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Evaluator {
    std::string descriptor{};
    unsigned int number{};
    // Extractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Evaluator& ev) {
        return is >> ev.descriptor >> ev.number;
    }
    // Inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Evaluator& ev) {
        return os << '\t' << ev.descriptor << '\t' << ev.number;
    }
};

struct Record {
    unsigned int ID{};
    unsigned int item{};
    std::vector<Evaluator> eval{};

    // Extractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Record& r) {
        std::string line{};
        if (std::getline(is, line)) {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            // Delete old data
            r.eval.clear();

            // Read attributes
            iss >> r.ID >> r.item;

            // Read all Evaluators
            Evaluator temp{};
            while (iss >> temp) {
                r.eval.push_back(std::move(temp));
            }
        }
        return is;
    }
    // Inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Record& r) {
        // Write main atributes
        os << r.ID << '\t' << r.item;
        // Write all evaluators
        for (const Evaluator& e : r.eval) os << e;
        return os;
    }
};
std::istringstream testFile{ R"(7001 2 OOP 4 POM 3 CS 4 Englh 3 Isl.st 2
7002 2 OOP 4 CS 4 Isl.St 2)" };

int main() {

    // All records (all lines)
    std::vector<Record> record;

    // Read all data
    Record r;
    while (testFile >> r) 
        record.push_back(std::move(r));

    // show debug output
    for (const Record& rr : record) std::cout << rr << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```